# What is the etymology of "Pasifika"?

Tags: etymology, new-zealand-english

What is the etymology of the term "Pasifika", which can [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasifika) the Pacific Islands, people of Pacific Island heritage (in a New Zealand context), or a festival held in Auckland about Pacific Island culture?

Comment: I feel like I should give this question a +1 and the answer a -1 (or vice versa) just so that proper order in the universe can be preserved.  :)

Comment: who knew ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a New Zealand English term derived from the Samoan version of a Portuguese version of a Latin phrase.

From [The New Zealand Herald](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/lifestyle/news/article.cfm?c_id=6&objectid=10455473)

> Pasifika is an odd term, and one gaining increasing currency outside
>   the annual festival at Western Springs. Essentially, its the
>   samoanisation of a Portuguese nod to the Latin phrase Mare Pacificum,
>   or peaceful sea, so named by navigator Ferdinand Magellan.

Comment: Wait... did you... at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

It comes from Niuean. Favoured by publication editors, academics and government as way of raising  awareness about the diversity of cultures.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which cultures? What/where is Niuea?

Comment: I can't elaborate with respect to etymology, but Niue is a tiny, single-island (well, coral reef) country in the Pacific, in free association with New Zealand (i.e. all Niueans are citizens of New Zealand). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niue